# Why does i + 2 result in an infinite loop where i += 2 doesn't?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm just going through freedcodecamp and I'm doing the "Iterate Odd Numbers With a For Loop" section. I just have a question with regards to some unintended effects I encountered.

```
const myArray = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
    myArray.push(i);
}
```

This is the correct answer and I got there no problem, however I'm wondering why changing the `i += 2` to `i + 2` generates an infinite loop?

Comment: because `i` does not change.

Comment: ... therefore the condition `i < 10` is never `false`

Comment: Hi Nina, I'm very very new to this, could you please explain why it doesn't change? When going through the tutorials it described += as a shorter way to type a var + number = and that was the only benefit it outlined.

Comment: @RyanNuttall Please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Because ```i + 2``` is not an assignment, it is an operation, so ```i``` will always remain ```1```, so each time will simply return ```3``` being less than ```10```

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, the explanations and links have helped me understand it.

Comment: `i += 2`, a shorthand for `i = i + 2`, or **take value of i, adds 2 to it, then assign it back to i** . For your question, `i + 2`, which means **take value of i, adds 2 to it THEN do nothing with it** since there is no assignment

Comment: To answer your earlier question, `i += 2` is shorthand for `i = i + 2`. It includes an assignment operator _and_ an arithmetic operator.